# Difference between end of a container and iterator pointing to an item inside. C++

Tags: c++, iterator

```
list<int> l;
list<int>::iterator start;
list<int>::iterator end;
list<int>::iterator mid;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    l.push_back(i);
start= l.begin();
end= l.end();
mid = start+ (end- start) / 2;
cout << *mid << endl;
```

Okay I have a concrete example now. end- start does not compile.

Comment: Did you intend to write `ble.begin() + (ble.begin() - ble.end()) / 2` or was it supposed to be `ble.begin() + (ble.end() - ble.begin()) / 2` ?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Doesn't compile? Doesn't give you the result you want?

Comment: I think he literally means `last - start / 2`, so `start/2` obviously doesn't compile.

Comment: just fixed it thanks  Adrian Panasiuk

Comment: Another typo ... pardon my mistakes..  - Adrian Panasiuk

Comment: Huh. If it's not `start/2` after all, then I second @remyabel's question: what do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you change the contents of the list `ble` after declaring `last` and `start`, but before attempting `start+(last-start)/2` ?

Comment: `end` does not point to the last element, it points to the position right after the last, because C++ iterators are half-open range based...

Comment: Yea end is literally after the last item. Pardon my crappy names.
Henrique Barcelos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` iterator is `Bidirectional iterator, it's not`Random access iterator`. You can't call`operator-` on it.

you could just try to use `std::advance` to move your iterator to the middle of container

```
std::advance(ble.begin(), ble.size()/2);
```